# What is the color white returned from the GetPixel() method?

Tags: c#, getpixel

What is the RBG value of the color white returned from the GetPixel() method?
Is it (255, 255, 255) or (0, 0, 0)?

Comment: Why don't you try it first?

Comment: We are talking about additive colors, which is the fact with RGB values on screens. It is 255,255,255 or `Color.White`.

Comment: in photoshop it is 255 255 255!is it different in c#?

Comment: @PayamHesami: No it is not.

Comment: @PayamHesami RGB can not be different :) it's standard as 1 meter -> it can not be 102cm in Photoshop, just can't :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

White = 255 255 255

Black = 0 0 0

There's an easy code to check it

```
  Byte r = Color.White.R; // r = 255
  Byte g = Color.White.G; // g = 255
  Byte b = Color.White.B; // b = 255
```